# Finding $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}|\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}|\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\left|\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}\right|\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{|(x-1)(y-2)^2|}{|(x-1)^2|+|\sin^2(y-2)|}\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{|\sin^2(y-2)|}$$

Can we say that is less or equal to $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{|\sin^2(y-2)|}$ as $\sin^2(y-2)$ is bounded by $|\sin^2(y-2)|\leq 1$

Comment: @g Again you do it: you begin a string of inequalities *without* using absolute value in the very first term but then using it in the following terms...This is useless and sometimes, as in your past question, can lead you to wrong expressions

Comment: Your second inquality is wrong: that's the usual, classic triangle inequality... **in the denominator** ! Either you put a minus sign before that $\;\sin^2(y-2)\;$ or else you change the inequality sign direction....and the you arrived nowhere.

Comment: @DonAntonio , Yes I am trying to learn how to use the absolute value, looking from the beginning on absolute value is correct? as for the second inequality I understand the mistake

Comment: Try to use polar coordinates and tend $r \to 0$.

Comment: Hint for the future. Hold off on the limit signs until the end. You don't know the limit exists at the beginning, so why write it? Plus they clutter up the joint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $|x-1|$ in your last expression. I'm not sure why you're writing the same expression repeatedly. You've essentially shown

$$\left | \frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}\right | \le |x-1|\frac{(y-2)^2}{\sin^2(y-2)}.$$

Now what to you know about $\dfrac{u^2}{\sin^2 u}$ as $u\to 0?$

Comment: it is the reciprocal of $lim_{x \to 0}\frac{sinx}{x}$ which is $1$

Answer (score 0):

And idea for you to check: substitute $\;s:=x-1\;,\;\;t:=y-2\;$ and evaluate the limit when $\;(s,t)\to(0,0)\;$ :

$$\left|\frac{st^2}{s^2+\sin^2t}\right|\le\left|\frac{st^2}{\sin^2t}\right|=\frac{|s|}{\left(\frac{\sin t}t\right)^2}\xrightarrow[(s,t)\to(0,0)]{}\frac0{1^2}=0$$

Or, after the substitutions, with polar coordinates:

$$\left|\frac{r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\left(r\sin\theta\right)}\right|\le\left|\frac{r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta}\right|= r|\sin\theta|\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$